# How can i fill one datatable column with rows and the other columns later?

Tags: c#, wpf

i get a few thousends Data from a Server, i want to write that data in a table, the problem is i don't know how can i fill only the first Column with rows. The second and third Column i want to fill later when i have the data for that.

Here my code to receive the Data and insert into the datatable:

```
while (true)
        {
            receiving_socket.Receive(receive_buffer);
            if (receive_buffer.Length > 0)
            {
                string data = CreateStringFromByteArray(receive_buffer);
                string[] arrayData = data.Split('/');
                foreach (string str in arrayData)
                {
                    neu = str;
                    //varNamenArray has all ColumnHeaders inside
                    for (int i = 0; i < varNamenArray.Length; i++) 
                    {
                        if (str == varNamenArray[i])
                        {
                            string nameColumnToFill = varNamenArray[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //insert the data in the column, i search something like the next row
                            //dataTable.nameColumnToFill.Item.Add(str);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: My Datatable has the Columnname as Header and already exits with all Columns but no Rows.

Comment: Depends on how much of the data you want to access. You could write one query that returns all row numbers, and wrap those numbers inside a class instances that lazy load the remaining fields for the given row number on request.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty row and then set the value of the particular column, e.g.:

```
DataRow newRow = dataTable.Rows.Add();
newRow[nameColumnToFill] = str;
```